# PHP Echo text Color change with $Product['title'] and String in php?

Tags: php, html, session

I want to echo success_flash in white color but I am not able to do it $product['title'].

Below line I want to echo all in white color but this line not working:

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['title'].'<span style="color:white;text-align:center;"> has been added to your cart!</span>';
```

I also tried

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span style="color:white;text-align:center;"> $product['title']</span>'. '<span style="color:white;text-align:center;"> has been added to your cart!</span>';
```

but this did not work for me either.

Comment: Seems to me that the inline CSS is overwritten? Could you check in your browser what is actually rendered?

Comment: `'<span style="color:white;text-align:center;"> $product['title']</span>'` won't work, should be `'<span style="color:white;text-align:center;">'. $product['title'] . '</span>'`

Comment: Use CSS classes to style different flash messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span style="color:white;text-align:center;">'. $product['title']. ' has been added to your cart!</span>';
```

or

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">'. $product['title']. ' has been added to your cart!</span>';
```

You can add background color to check if working and then can remove backgrond color

like

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span style="background-color:#FF0000; padding:5px; color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">'. $product['title'] . ' has been added to your cart!</span>';
```

or try using css class like below

```
<style>
.myspan {
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span class="myspan">'. $product['title']. ' has been added to your cart!</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) to force override a previous `color` value, although it may not be the best practice:

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '
    <span style="color:white!important;text-align:center;">
        '.$product['title'].'
    </span>
    <span style="color:white!important;text-align:center;"> 
        has been added to your cart!
    </span>
';
```